# Error "cannot download, $GOPATH not set."

Tags: go

**Setup:**

Have a look at my configuration:

```
$ echo $GOPATH && ls -r $GOPATH
/home/cyrus/.go
src  pkg  bin

$ echo $GOROOT && ls $GOROOT
/usr/local/go
api  AUTHORS  bin  CONTRIBUTORS  doc  favicon.ico  include  lib  LICENSE  misc  PATENTS  pkg  README  robots.txt  src  test  VERSION
```

You can see that I've set a path for `$GOPATH`. In addition, I've created subdirectories that I may not need.

**Question:**

Why does the following command generate this error message?

```
$ go get code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour                                                                                                               
package code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you set a variable like this:

```
GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

It won't be exported to any subprocesses. It's only available to that process. If you want to export it to subprocesses, use `export`:

```
export GOPATH
```

You can also combine the assignment and export:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

Comment: Further, you can confirm your Go settings with `go env` - if `GOPATH` is not set/incorrect it will show.

Comment: Done all of this and still doesn't work when using `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`, `go env` even prints out the environment and it looks perfect.

Comment: I just want to install Gogs, because Gitlab doesn´t work on my server and I´m struggelin arround for hours again because of configuration errors....unbelievable

Answer (score 1):

My $GOROOT directory was created with `owner: root` and `group: wheel` instead having me as the owner and admin as the group. I'll guess that I used sudo when I shouldn't have (or some tool did it for me). As such `go get` could not write the packages to $GOROOT and hence the `$GOPATH not set` and `permission denied` errors.

By using `chown` and `chgrp` on my $GOROOT (with -R to get subfolders) 'go get...' worked. In my case VS Code was now able to install the Go components I was after.

Comment: `I used sudo when I shouldn't have` saved me

Answer (score 1):

When you run go env, you should be able to see if your GOPATH has been set.
On my case though, this command solves it when I had it run on my terminal.

```
export GOPATH=/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

i had setup `GOPATH` and it showed correctly with command `go env`. i had to give the correct permissions to the go directory using `chmod` and install `gb` by `go get github.com/constabulary/gb/...`.

Answer (score 0):

First do a `go env' and check the path GOROOT. Accordingly set the GOPATH.
In my case, it had to set GOPATH to /usr/lib/go. Earlier i tried it with /usr/share/go and /usr/bin/go but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

$GOPATH should be your current workspace , a folder where your project resides.
or just cd ~/go and try to run those commands.
Or you can just update $GOPATH in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bashrc_profile on ubuntu