# GOPATH environment variable not set

Tags: linux, oracle, go, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to install the Oracle Driver for Go (go-oci8) following these [instructions](https://github.com/Centny/Centny/blob/master/Articles/How%20build%20github.com:mattn:go-oci8.md)

The problem I'm facing is with the $GOPATH environment variable. 
When I execute the command:

`sudo go get github.com/mattn/go-oci8`

I get the error :

`cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath`

However, I have the GOPATH properly set. My environment looks like this:

`env | grep GO`

`GOARCH=amd64`
`GOROOT=/usr/local/go`
`GOOS=linux`
`GOPATH=/home/myuser/go/`

`ls $GOPATH`
`bin    pkg    src`

I've found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872223/cannot-download-gopath-not-set) but the solution does not apply to my case.

Comment: Did you try `sudo GOPATH=/home/myuser/go/ go get github.com/mattn/go-oci8`?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep Environment Variables when Using SUDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo)

Comment: It is not "Why are you using sudo?", it is "Do not use sudo!".

Comment: The instructions on the page you linked to don't say to use `sudo`. You *really* don't need to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sudo won't honor all your ENV variables for some very good security reasons.

The simplest way to fix this is /bin/env

```
sudo /bin/env GOPATH=/home/myuser/go go get <stuff>
```

But you don't need to do that, you really shouldn't need root to write 
to GOPATH, only GOROOT.

Comment: having used ruby on rails, I like RVM to manage ruby environments and versions. I was glad to find GVM for Go: https://github.com/moovweb/gvm

Comment: I was actually using sudo because I was having issues with permission. All I did was create the GO directories again and install the package without the use of SUDO. It's working now. Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: Using sudo can be necessary though, e.g. when working with raw sockets.

Comment: You can also do `$ sudo -E go get <stuff>`.