# cannot download, $GOPATH not set

Tags: macos, installation, go

I want to install json2csv using `go get github.com/jehiah/json2csv` but I receive this error:

```
package github.com/jehiah/json2csv: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help go path
```

Any help on how to fix this on MacOS?

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872223/cannot-download-gopath-not-set

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a different package (pup).  C'mon Go maintainers, please make an (OS X) installer that finishes the job!  The OS X installer for Node is a great example.  Using Node does not require additional manual installation steps.  It just works.  I hope future versions of the Go installer will be better.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

[Update: as of Go 1.8, `GOPATH` defaults to `$HOME/go`, but you may still find this useful if you want to understand the `GOPATH` layout, customize it, etc.]

The official Go site [discusses GOPATH and how to lay out a workspace directory](http://golang.org/doc/code.html).

`export GOPATH="$HOME/your-workspace-dir/"` -- run it in your shell, then add it to `~/.bashrc` or equivalent so it will be set for you in the future. Go will install packages under `src/`, `bin/`, and `pkg/`, subdirectories there. You'll want to put your own packages somewhere under `$GOPATH/src`, like `$GOPATH/src/github.com/myusername/` if you want to publish to GitHub. You'll also probably want `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` in your `.bashrc` so you can run compiled programs under `$GOPATH`.

Optionally, [via Rob Pike](https://twitter.com/rob_pike/status/467367507305574400), you can also set `CDPATH` so it's faster to `cd` to package dirs in bash: `export CDPATH=.:$GOPATH/src/github.com:$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x` means you can just type `cd net/html` instead of `cd $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/net/html`.

Keith Rarick [notes](https://twitter.com/krarick/status/467035722436718593) you can set `GOPATH=$HOME` to put Go's `src/`, `pkg/` and `bin/` directories right under your homedir. That can be nice (for instance, you might already have `$HOME/bin` in your path) but of course some folks use multiple workspaces, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you need to change your workspace for each individual project?

Comment: In general, no, you can use one workspace whose `src/` contains e.g. `github.com/youruser/x` and `github.com/youruser/y`. That's what I do. People might have their reasons to do otherwise (company policy to keep projects apart?), but I can't speak to that.

Comment: $GOPATH is set, but "cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath" appears anyway.

Comment: What platform (Windows or Linux/OS X/other Unix)? If not Windows, what does`echo $GOPATH` say? It might be worth posting as a separate question; it sounds like you're in some unusual situation, and debugging those in comments can be tricky.

Comment: @Tyguy7 chances are you didn't `export` it; run `/bin/bash -c "echo \$GOPATH"` to verify that sub-processes can see `$GOPATH`; if it echos empty, then run `export GOPATH` and then `go get ...`

Answer (score 97):

This one worked

[Setting up Go development environment on Ubuntu, and how to fix $GOPATH / $GOROOT](https://web.archive.org/web/20150822031237/http://renyikhor.com:80/blog/installing-go-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-fix-gopath-goroot/)

**Steps**

```
mkdir ~/go
```

Set $GOPATH in .bashrc,

```
export GOPATH=~/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: Link is dead now.

Answer (score 34):

#### Using brew

I installed it using `brew`.

```
$ brew install go
```

When it was done if you run this brew command it'll show the following info:

```
$ brew info go
go: stable 1.4.2 (bottled), HEAD
Go programming environment
https://golang.org
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2 (4676 files, 158M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/go.rb
==> Options
--with-cc-all
    Build with cross-compilers and runtime support for all supported platforms
--with-cc-common
    Build with cross-compilers and runtime support for darwin, linux and windows
--without-cgo
    Build without cgo
--without-godoc
    godoc will not be installed for you
--without-vet
    vet will not be installed for you
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
As of go 1.2, a valid GOPATH is required to use the `go get` command:
  https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH

You may wish to add the GOROOT-based install location to your PATH:
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
```

The important pieces there are these lines:

> /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2 (4676 files, 158M) *
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin

#### Setting up GO's environment

That shows where GO was installed. We need to do the following to setup GO's environment:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
$ export GOPATH=/usr/local/opt/go/bin
```

You can then check using GO to see if it's configured properly:

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/usr/local/opt/go/bin"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

#### Setting up json2csv

Looks good, so lets install `json2csv`:

```
$ go get github.com/jehiah/json2csv
$
```

What just happened? It installed it. You can check like this:

```
$ $ ls -l $GOPATH/bin
total 5248
-rwxr-xr-x  1 sammingolelli  staff  2686320 Jun  9 12:28 json2csv
```

OK, so why can't I type `json2csv` in my shell? That's because the `/bin` directory under `$GOPATH` isn't on your `$PATH`.

```
$ type -f json2csv
-bash: type: json2csv: not found
```

So let's temporarily add it:

```
$ export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

And re-check:

```
$ type -f json2csv
json2csv is hashed (/usr/local/opt/go/bin/bin/json2csv)
```

Now it's there:

```
$ json2csv --help
Usage of json2csv:
  -d=",": delimiter used for output values
  -i="": /path/to/input.json (optional; default is stdin)
  -k=[]: fields to output
  -o="": /path/to/output.json (optional; default is stdout)
  -p=false: prints header to output
  -v=false: verbose output (to stderr)
  -version=false: print version string
```

Add the modifications we've made to `$PATH` and `$GOPATH` to your `$HOME/.bash_profile` to make them persist between reboots.

Answer (score 18):

### Watch a Video

In general, I always recommend this official video from Go to get a quick overview on the matter:

**http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCsL89YtqCs**

*It's easier to be shown than to be told.*

[@jwfearn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10559/jwfearn) paraphrased the important part of the video:

> `export GOPATH="${HOME}/gocode"; export PATH="${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin"; mkdir -p "${GOPATH}"`

Comment: Excellent introductory video - I always understand better when it's shown to me.

Comment: Thanks @jwfearn - videos are for music and other entertainment; can't copy & paste from them :-)

Answer (score 6):

I found easier to do it like this:

```
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export GOPATH=$GOROOT/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH
```

Answer (score 4):

For MAC this worked well for me.

```
sudo nano /etc/bashrc
```

and add the below at the end of the file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
export GOPATH=/usr/local/opt/go/bin
```

This should fix the problem. Try opening a new terminal and echo $GOPATH you should see the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

***(for MAC)***

I tried all these answers and, for some still unknown reason, none of them worked.

I had to "force feed" the GOPATH by setting the environment variable per every command that required it. For example:

```
sudo env GOPATH=$HOME/goWorkDirectory go build ...
```

Even `glide` was giving me the `GOPATH not set` error. Resolved it, again, by "force feeding":
    I tried all these answers and, for some still unknown reason, none of them worked.

I had to "force feed" the GOPATH by setting the environment variable per every command that required it.

```
sudo env GOPATH=$HOME/goWorkDirectory glide install
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$GOROOT` should not be set up. 
You `$GOPATH` should be set to `$HOME/go` by typing `export $GOPATH=$HOME/go`

Please type `export GOROOT=""` to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `export GOPATH="/whatever/you/like/your/GOPATH/to/be"`.

Comment: If I'm a go noob, I don't yet know "where I'd like my GOPATH to be".  IMHO it's a drag that there is not a *default* GOPATH behavior which can be *overridden* by an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem after having `$GOPATH` set up, it may be because you're running it with an unsupported shell. I was using `fish` and it did not work, launching it with `bash` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "export" solution just like what other guys have suggested. I'd like to provide you with another solution for permanent convenience: you can use any path as GOPATH when running Go commands.

Firstly, you need to download a small tool named `gost` : https://github.com/byte16/gost/releases . If you use ubuntu, you can download the linux version(https://github.com/byte16/gost/releases/download/v0.1.0/gost_linux_amd64.tar.gz).

Then you need to run the commands below to unpack it :

```
$ cd /path/to/your/download/directory 
$ tar -xvf gost_linux_amd64.tar.gz
```

You would get an executable `gost`.  You can move it to `/usr/local/bin` for convenient use:

```
$ sudo mv gost /usr/local/bin
```

Run the command below to add the path you want to use as GOPATH into the **pathspace** `gost` maintains. It is required to give the path a name which you would use later.

```
$ gost add foo /home/foobar/bar     # 'foo' is the name and '/home/foobar/bar' is the path
```

Run any Go command you want in the format:

```
gost goCommand [-p {pathName}] -- [goFlags...] [goArgs...]
```

For example, you want to run `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` with `/home/foobar/bar` as the GOPATH, just do it as below:

```
$ gost get -p foo -- github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql  # 'foo' is the name you give to the path above.
```

It would help you to set the GOPATH and run the command. But remember that you have added the path into `gost`'s **pathspace**. If you are under any level of subdirectories of `/home/foobar/bar`, you can even just run the command below which would do the same thing for short :

```
$ gost get -- github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

`gost` is a Simple Tool of Go which can help you to manage GOPATHs and run Go commands. For more details about how to use it to run other Go commands, you can just run `gost help goCmdName`. For example you want to know more about `install`, just type words below in:

```
$ gost help install
```

You can also find more details in the README of the project: https://github.com/byte16/gost/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Run 'go env' and see where your GOPATH is currently pointing towards. If you change to that directory, your 'go get..etc' command should work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured to me in raspberry pi. I had logged in through VNC client 
The problem persisted despite setting and exporting the GOPATH. 
Then Ran the "go get" command without sudo and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using vim to edit my .bashrc file but you code use a gui editor such as `gedit`.

Steps:

Kindly subsitute `/path/to/golang/projects` below with your actual path location where you will store your golang projects.

Open .bashrc file in vim that is `vim ~/.bashrc`. Then add below lines at the end of the file.

```
# Setup Golang Development Environment ::
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
 
# Third party go libraries will live under "~/golib" directory
export GOPATH="$HOME/golib"
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
 
# Where your golang project code lives
export GOPATH=$GOPATH:/path/to/golang/projects
```

Save the file and type `source ~/.bashrc` to refresh your terminal session.
Now try getting a package e.g. `go get github.com/pilu/fresh` and check your `~/golib/bin` directory it should have `fresh` package in it.

Navigate to your `/path/to/golang/projects` and create three folders in there i.e. `bin`,`src` and `pkg`

Now place your project folder inside `/path/to/golang/projects/src`  e.g. `/path/to/golang/projects/src/myfancygolangproject`and you should be good to go. Put all your golang codebase in there mate.

Answer (score -1):

I had to run an application as root (to open a webserver on port 80), this produced the error for me, because the sudo user has a different environment than the normal user, hence GOPATH was not set.

If someone else is having this problem, add `-E` to the command, this will preserve the user environment.

`sudo -E go run main.go`

For more infos see discussion here: [Google Groups – GOPATH Problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7HvbTsxa5tA)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but fixed it for me…