# importing go files in same folder

Tags: import, path, go

I am having difficulty in importing a local go file into another go file.

My project structure is like something below

```
-samplego
--pkg
--src
---github.com
----xxxx
-----a.go
-----b.go
--bin
```

I am trying to import a.go inside b.go. I tried the following,

```
import "a"
import "github.com/xxxx/a"
```

None of these worked..I understand I have to meddle up with GOPATH but I couldn't get it right. Presently my GOPATH is pointing to samplego(/workspace/samplego).I get the below error

```
cannot find package "a" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/a (from $GOROOT)
/workspace/samplego/src/a (from $GOPATH)
```

Also, how does GOPATH work when these source files are imported into another project/module? Would the local imports be an issue then? What is the best practice in this case - is it to have just one go file in module(with associated tests)?

Comment: Any number of files in a directory are part of the same package from the start. (And they need to have the same `package a` declaration at the top.)

Comment: Thanks @twotwotwo...Could you let me know how to solve the above issue? Also, when we have multipe go files in a package should the import follow full path eg. github.com/xxxx/a or just a would do

Comment: For Go modules, files in the same directory are still part of the same package, still need to have the same package name (e.g., `package foo`), and still do not need to directly import each other. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314494/11210494) covers this a bit more for Go modules, including how to import packages in the same module under Go modules.

Comment: This post still ranks high on search results but go changed the recommended way of how to structure a go project.

would be nice a small edit pointing it out so newbies don't end up trying to setup GOPATH or go workspaces instead of create a go module https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Any number of files in a directory are a single package; symbols declared in one file are available to the others without any `import`s or qualifiers. All of the files do need the same `package foo` declaration at the top (or you'll get an error from `go build`).

You do need `GOPATH` set to the directory where your `pkg`, `src`, and `bin` directories reside. This is just a matter of preference, but it's common to have a single workspace for all your apps (sometimes `$HOME`), not one per app.

Normally a Github path would be `github.com/username/reponame` (not just `github.com/xxxx`). So if you want to have `main` and another package, you may end up doing something under `workspace/src` like

```
github.com/
  username/
    reponame/
      main.go   // package main, importing "github.com/username/reponame/b"
      b/
        b.go    // package b
```

Note you always import with the full `github.com/...` path: relative imports aren't allowed in a workspace. If you get tired of typing paths, use `goimports`. If you were getting by with `go run`, it's time to switch to `go build`: `run` deals poorly with multiple-file `main`s and I didn't bother to test but heard (from Dave Cheney [here](https://plus.google.com/+ChalmersBrown/posts/KgEV8Y8eFwe)) `go run` doesn't rebuild dirty dependencies.

Sounds like you've at least tried to set GOPATH to the right thing, so if you're still stuck, maybe include exactly how you set the environment variable (the command, etc.) and what command you ran and what error happened. [Here are instructions on how to set it (and make the setting persistent) under Linux/UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628918/cannot-download-gopath-not-set/20629533#20629533) and [here is the Go team's advice on workspace setup](http://golang.org/doc/code.html). Maybe neither helps, but take a look and at least point to which part confuses you if you're confused.

Comment: goimports was quite helpful :)

Comment: If you are having trouble running multiple files in the main package, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28081554/616644).

Comment: I added the same `package main` declaration to all files in the same directory, but I have the `undefined` error, `main.go` cannot see functions from file `controllers.go` which is in the same directory.

Comment: @AlexChaliy If you're using `go run`, you may need to explicitly pass both filenames to it, or switch to putting them in a package in your GOPATH and `go build`ing it. Also double-check for common errors unrelated to package structure (like a typoed name). If none of that solves it, I'd open a new question with all the detail you can; it might take a lot of discussion of precisely how _your_ dir, files, etc. look to solve, and since it'd be specifically about your setup a new question seems like the best venue for that.

Comment: Excellent answer, learned many new things in a single answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 62):

No import is necessary as long as you declare both `a.go` and `b.go` to be in the same package. Then, you can use `go run` to recognize multiple files with:

```
$ go run a.go b.go
```

Comment: this is what's needed for a quick and dirty exploration. Also worth mentioning that the package name at the top of each file needs to be 'main' for this to work.

Answer (score 19):

> ./main.go (in package main) 
>   ./a/a.go (in package a) 
>   ./a/b.go (in package a)

in this case:
main.go import "./a"

It can call the function in the a.go and b.go,that with first letter caps on.

Answer (score 10):

**If none of the above answers works,**

Just try,

```
go run .
```

for production,

```
go build
```

This will take care of all the **.go** files in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted something really basic to move some files out of the main folder, like  user2889485's reply, but his specific answer didnt work for me. I didnt care if they were in the same package or not.

My GOPATH workspace is `c:\work\go` and under that I have

```
/src/pg/main.go      (package main)
/src/pg/dbtypes.go   (pakage dbtypes)
```

in `main.go` I  `import "/pg/dbtypes"`

Answer (score 1):

As people mentioned previously, there is no need to use any imports.
A lot of people mention that using go run is possibe when you mention most files, however when having **multiple .go-files** in the same dir it can be cumbersome.
Therefore using `go run *.go` is what I usually do.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand for packages in your project subfolders it's possible now to do, just need to add "." in front of module, like
`. "github.com/ilyasf/deadlock-train/common"`
where github.com/ilyasf/deadlock-train my main module name and common is just package from /common subfolder inside project.