# Can vim-go completion third party framework

Tags: vim, go

I use vim-go plugin and it can autocompletion the build in framework such as "*fmt*", "*os*" etc. But cannot completion third party framework.

Comment: I think `vim-go` needs to know your GOPATH. If you export it in your shell before starting `vim`, I think that's what it takes (but I'm not a vim-go user). More about setting GOPATH [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628918/cannot-download-gopath-not-set/20629533#20629533).

Comment: Thank's, I was already export GOPATH, but cannot work.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.You need to install the gocode daemon, which you can do via `:GoInstallBinaries` once vim-go is installed.

See the [README](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/README.md) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Oh... It's my fault, I didn't config the *gocode*

```
➜  ~ gocode set lib-path "$GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64"
lib-path "$GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64"
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ gocode set
propose-builtins true
lib-path "$GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64"
autobuild true
force-debug-output ""
package-lookup-mode "go"
➜  ~
```

Now, it works well!