# Go custom package import error

Tags: go

I am trying to write a program where I have a structure like:

```
Go/src/
  -github.com
     -myname
        -hello
           main.go
           -vector
              vector.go
```

When I import the package in my code inside of the `main.go` file using a command like:

```
import(
  "vector"
)
```

I get the error message:

```
Can't find package "vector" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\vendor\vector (vendor tree)
    C:\Go\src\vertex (from $GOROOT)
    C:\Go\src\github.com\myname\src\vertex (from $GOPATH)
```

Why is it adding `src` on that last line?  Shouldn't it replace the src with the hello folder since that is where I'm running the file from?  Also, it runs if I import it from the full file structure like `github.com/myname/hello/vertex` which seems strange to me.

I am executing using `go run hello.go` to simplify my interaction with the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Go code (as opposed to Go's stdlib) is meant to be under `$GOPATH/src` (edit: *not* `$GOROOT`, as I initially said!), and it's standard to always use the full import path, in your case starting with `github.com/` (even if you figured out a way to avoid having to).

There is more in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) by the Go team, and other answers here describing [project layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867452/what-is-a-sensible-way-to-layout-a-go-project) and [the first steps to setting a workspace up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628918/cannot-download-gopath-not-set).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, my personal code goes in the `$GOROOT/src`, but if I import a repo from someone else's code, I would put that in the `$GOROOT/src/github.com/username/reponame` folder?

Comment: A user's code is supposed to be under $GOPATH[/src], not $GOROOT[/src].

Comment: @cd1 ugh, very sorry, fixed

Comment: @Rob -- see above; I was dead wrong. Generally, your code and other people's code should be in a similar structure -- see "the first steps..." link for an example where you make `$GOPATH/src/github.com/youruser"